# Recoil state is reset when the component unmounts

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, recoiljs

I am working on a react project where I have a table of paginated entries fetched from the backend and when I click on any entry, I navigate to a page where all details of this entry are being displayed. The point is, I am using recoil to manage the state of my project and I initialized a state inside an atom with the following values:

```
{
 offset: 0,
 totalItems: 0,
 searchType: "all",
 loading: false,
 error: false,
 data: [],
}
```

The offset here represents the page number and the totalItems is used to calculate the total number of pages. The point here is, I make an asynchronous call whenever I navigate from one page to another, and therefore, I change the value of the initial state which is ok so far. However, when I am on the 3rd page -for instance- and I navigate to one of the entries' details page (the offset now is 2), I always find the offset reset back to 0 when I navigate back the page that has the table of entries despite not resetting the state of recoil myself. Is this behavior intended or am I doing something wrong?

I use this recoil hook to retrieve the state and set the new value:

```
 // Fetch the global state from recoil to be used within the component
 const [entries, setEntries] = useRecoilState(entriesObject);
```

I take redux as a reference because it never resets the state unless you do it inside the reducer by yourself but now I see that the state -somehow- resets for no reason. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [like this](https://tsplay.dev/m0orGN) but with your code.

Comment: Without more infomation I'm only guessing, but it sounds like your `RecoilRoot` might be surrounding the list component, rather than the whole app.  So, when you navigate to an entry page, the recoil state is lost because the RecoilRoot is unloaded.  It is then set to it's default the next time you load the list page.

Where is the `RecoilRoot` in relation to the rest of your app?